# Xamarin - An error occurred trying to install required android components on Project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a new Xamarin portable project in VS 2015 and I'm always getting that error

> An error occurred trying to install required android components on
>   Project 'FirstApp.Android'. Project 'FirstApp.Android' requires the
>   following components installed on your machine: 
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Design JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.3.0/design-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   AndroidResources:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.3.0/design-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.3.0/support-v4-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.3.0/support-v4-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   AndroidResources:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.3.0/support-v4-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/support-vector-drawable/23.3.0/support-vector-drawable-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   AndroidResources:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/support-vector-drawable/23.3.0/support-vector-drawable-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/animated-vector-drawable/23.3.0/animated-vector-drawable-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   AndroidResources:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/animated-vector-drawable/23.3.0/animated-vector-drawable-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.3.0/appcompat-v7-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   AndroidResources:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.3.0/appcompat-v7-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/23.3.0/mediarouter-v7-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   JavaLibraryReference:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/23.3.0/mediarouter-v7-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>   AndroidResources:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/23.3.0/mediarouter-v7-23.3.0.aar-23.3.0.0
>
> Please double-click here to install it.
>
> Intallation Errors: XA5207 Please install package:
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in SDK installer. Java
>   library file
>   'C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar'
>   doesn't exist. XA5207 Please install package:
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library
>   file
>   'C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar'
>   doesn't exist. XA5207 Please install package:
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library
>   file
>   'C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\content\libs/internal_impl-23.3.0.jar'
>   doesn't exist. XA5207 Please install package:
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer.
>   Java library file
>   'C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar'
>   doesn't exist. XA5207 Please install package:
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK
>   installer. Java library file
>   'C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar'
>   doesn't exist. XA5207 Please install package:
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer.
>   Java library file
>   'C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar'
>   doesn't exist. XA5207 Please install package:
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer.
>   Java library file
>   'C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\content\classes.jar'
>   doesn't exist. XA5207 Please install package:
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer.
>   Java library file
>   'C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\content\libs/internal_impl-23.3.0.jar'
>   doesn't exist.            0

What I have tried

**Reinstalling Xamarin.Android.Support.Design**

- It started showing me a similar error for the
  Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter package
- When I tried to    reinstall the
  Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter it started    showing the
  error message for the  Xamarin.Android.Support.Design    package
  again

**Downloading the missing files**

- Downloaded the zip file at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip
- Extracted the content of the design folder and copied it to C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.0.0\content\

nothing worked and I'm now stuck and couldn't think of anything else to try

Comment: This also looks similar to an issue described here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/219446/xamarin-an-error-occurred-trying-to-install-requir.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Appearntly what I needed to do is to delete the zip file in the path
C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zipped as it was corrupted and the visual studio will take care of re-downloading it on the next build.

Note: you could also download the files from  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and rename it to the same name of the file inside the zipped folder

Comment: More detailed info and step-by-step can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors#Manually_Downloading_m2repository

Answer (score 0):

Had the same kind of error. I just ran the following steps;

- Right click android project and click ***Manage NuGet Packages***
- Under Updates tab, update every pacakge that starts with **Xamarin.Android.Support.***
- After running updates, restart VS